# Is an Android Bluetooth LE Peripheral IP static?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, android-bluetooth

I am porting an iPhone app over to `Android` that utilises `Bluetooth LE`.
In the iPhone app, I scan a custom Bluetooth peripheral and store it's device UUID number as a string. This allows me to compare it later when the device is connected again.

`BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID` can supposedly be used to read the peripheral UUID in Android but i'm not sure how to use that to get the UUID as a device is connecting. Can anyone help with this please?

Also, Android does give me what looks like an IP address for the peripheral when calling `getAddress()`. I'm assuming this IP address is randomly created by the Android device when the peripheral is first discovered.

Are these IP's static, as in I can rely on them to identify each bluetooth peripheral during future launches of my app?
Or will they/could they change over time, ie. after device reboots etc..

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [BluetoothDevice#ACTION_UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_UUID)?

Comment: Thats to broadcast a UUID. I want to read it from the peripheral.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks, I have followed that, but it doesn't show how to get the peripheral UUID. On iOS this is available immediately after a connect, without having to read all the GATT profiles first. I'd also like an answer regarding the reliability of the IP that's given to a BT device. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget that UUID. What you should use instead in order to identify the peripheral in future connection is the peripheral's Bluetooth Address. The class `BluetoothDevice` has the method `getAddress()` which returns exactly that.

Then, in the LeScanCallback, check for this address again (String equality).

Comment: Thanks. What `getAddress()` returns is exactly what I was referring to in my question sorry. Bluetooth peripherals don't have an address like this, they have a UUID, so Android basically assigns this address to the peripheral. Will this address always be the same for this peripheral on the device it's been assigned? I know iOS has a habit of frequently changing the assigned IP address of a peripheral, but using the UUID is always the same. Thanks

Comment: @Darren What iOS (and maybe Android too) does is change **its own address** every once in a while (15 minutes I believe) for obvious security reasons. The peripheral's address is usually **static** though, so don't expect it to change. Also, the `getAddress()` returns the static address of the peripheral that gets transmitted in the advertising packet. It is **not** an id assigned by the phone.

Comment: Excellent. That's all I needed to know. So I can store the address and compare it on future connections. Thank you.